# Mygeneration autonumber field bug with MS Access database

Tags: mygeneration

I am using Mygeneration tools to create the abstract classes responsible for dealing with database to perform CRUD operation as well as some other dooDad operations. Problem is I cant retrieve the auto number field (it is also Primary Key) of table using the code

```
    Employees newObj = new Employees();
newObj.ConnectionString = connectionString;
newObj.AddNew();

// Your Properties will be different here
newObj.FirstName = "Joe";
newObj.LastName = "Plank Plank";

newObj.Save();
int staffid=newObj.StaffID;
```

The same thing is working fine in MS SQL server or other databases. Looks like auto number is not generated instantly which can be accessed once I added the entry. But, later, when I am checking the database, I found that auto number is generated there. Not sure, why this is happening. Anybody having expertise with dooDads, please help with info.

Edited:
The main problem is I cant access the autonumber field instantly after I create the fresh row entry. Looks like MS Access autonumber takes some time to show up and even in VS, you can see this phenomenon. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Strange, nobody faced this problem yet? I am the first?

Answer (score 0):

I have built many applications using Doodads , using MS Access , you have only  to make the filed as autonumber .. and generate the stored procedures and other classes.
i.e your code should work ..

also I made modification to Dodads to return list of Objects 
[How to get list of objects from BusinessEntity using myGeneration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349198/how-to-get-list-of-objects-from-businessentity-using-mygeneration)

Comment: That field is autonumber type. Actually I can access that field later time, but instantly after I add the fresh row entry, I cant access that autonumber field. You will also agree that if you add data to MS Access database table, the autonumber field shows up a bit later. How to fix it?

Comment: you can access the autonumber field after Calling Save() normally, otherwise I use s_ID instead of ID.